# I can not access this pine script alerts, i can not solve this problem, plz, solve this

Tags: pine-script

Add to Chart operation failed, reason:
line 71: Undeclared identifier 'lime';
line 71: Undeclared identifier 'gray';
line 78: Undeclared identifier 'line';
line 78: Undeclared identifier 'red';
line 79: Undeclared identifier 'line';
line 79: Undeclared identifier 'fuchsia';
line 80: Undeclared identifier 'line';
line 80: Undeclared identifier 'orange'

plz, solve this problem, i can not access the alerts.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © EzQuant

//@version=4

study("Ez Vix FIX / StochRSI Alerts", overlay=false)

///////////// Stochastic Slow

Stochlength = input(14, minval=1, title="lookback length of Stochastic")

StochOverBought = input(80, title="Stochastic overbought condition")
StochOverSold = input(20, title="Stochastic oversold condition")

smoothK = input(3, title="smoothing of Stochastic %K ")

smoothD = input(3, title="moving average of Stochastic %K")

k = sma(stoch(close, high, low, Stochlength), smoothK)

d = sma(k, smoothD)

 
///////////// RSI 

RSIlength = input( 12, minval=1 , title="lookback length of RSI")

RSIOverBought = input( 65  , title="RSI overbought condition")

RSIOverSold = input( 35  , title="RSI oversold condition")

RSIprice = close
vrsi = rsi(RSIprice, RSIlength)

///////////// Double strategy: RSI strategy + Stochastic strategy

pd = input(22, title="LookBack Period Standard Deviation High")

bbl = input(20, title="Bolinger Band Length")

mult = input(2.0    , minval=1, maxval=5, title="Bollinger Band Standard Devaition Up")

lb = input(50  , title="Look Back Period Percentile High")

ph = input(.85, title="Highest Percentile - 0.90=90%, 0.95=95%, 0.99=99%")

new = input(false, title="-------Text Plots Below Use Original Criteria-------" )

sbc = input(false, title="Show Text Plot if WVF WAS True and IS Now False")

sbcc = input(false, title="Show Text Plot if WVF IS True")

new2 = input(false, title="-------Text Plots Below Use FILTERED Criteria-------" )

sbcFilt = input(true, title="Show Text Plot For Filtered Entry")

sbcAggr = input(true, title="Show Text Plot For AGGRESSIVE Filtered Entry")

ltLB = input(40, minval=25, maxval=99, title="Long-Term Look Back Current Bar Has To Close Below This Value OR Medium Term--Default=40")

mtLB = input(14, minval=10, maxval=20, title="Medium-Term Look Back Current Bar Has To Close Below This Value OR Long Term--Default=14")

str = input(3, minval=1, maxval=9, title="Entry Price Action Strength--Close > X Bars Back---Default=3")

//Alerts Instructions and Options Below...Inputs Tab

new4 = input(false, title="-------------------------Turn On/Off ALERTS Below---------------------" )

new5 = input(false, title="----To Activate Alerts You HAVE To Check The Boxes Below For Any Alert Criteria You Want----")

sa1 = input(false, title="Show Alert WVF = True?")

sa2 = input(false, title="Show Alert WVF Was True Now False?")

sa3 = input(false, title="Show Alert WVF Filtered?")

sa4 = input(false, title="Show Alert WVF AGGRESSIVE Filter?")

//Williams Vix Fix Formula

wvf = ((highest(close, pd)-low)/(highest(close, pd)))*100

sDev = mult * stdev(wvf, bbl)

midLine = sma(wvf, bbl)

lowerBand = midLine - sDev

upperBand = midLine + sDev

rangeHigh = (highest(wvf, lb)) * ph

//Filtered Bar Criteria

upRange = low > low[1] and close > high[1]

upRange_Aggr = close > close[1] and close > open[1]

//Filtered Criteria

filtered = ((wvf[1] >= upperBand[1] or wvf[1] >= rangeHigh[1]) and (wvf < upperBand and wvf < rangeHigh))

filtered_Aggr = (wvf[1] >= upperBand[1] or wvf[1] >= rangeHigh[1]) and not (wvf < upperBand and wvf < rangeHigh)

//Alerts Criteria

alert1 = wvf >= upperBand or wvf >= rangeHigh ? 1 : 0

alert2 = (wvf[1] >= upperBand[1] or wvf[1] >= rangeHigh[1]) and (wvf < upperBand and wvf < rangeHigh) ? 1 : 0

alert3 = upRange and close > close[str] and (close < close[ltLB] or close < close[mtLB]) and filtered ? 1 : 0

alert4 = upRange_Aggr and close > close[str] and (close < close[ltLB] or close < close[mtLB]) and filtered_Aggr ? 1 : 0

//Coloring Criteria of Williams Vix Fix

col = wvf >= upperBand or wvf >= rangeHigh ? lime : gray

isOverBought = (crossover(k,d) and k > StochOverBought) ? 1 : 0

isOverBoughtv2 = k > StochOverBought ? 1 : 0
filteredAlert = alert3 ? 1 : 0

aggressiveAlert = alert4 ? 1 : 0

plot(isOverBought, "Overbought / Crossover", style=line, color=red) 

plot(filteredAlert, "Filtered Alert", style=line, color=fuchsia) 

plot(aggressiveAlert, "Aggressive Alert", style=line, color=orange)

Buy = (filteredAlert or aggressiveAlert)

Sell = (isOverBought)

alertcondition(Buy,  title='Ez Vix FIX / StochRSI, Long Alert',  message='BUY EzCONTINUOUS {{ticker}} {{high}} {{low}} {{close}}')

alertcondition(Sell, title='Ez Vix FIX / StochRSI, Short Alert', message='SELL EzCONTINUOUS {{ticker}} {{high}} {{low}} {{close}}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © EzQuant

//@version=4

study("Ez Vix FIX / StochRSI Alerts", overlay=false)

///////////// Stochastic Slow

Stochlength = input(14, minval=1, title="lookback length of Stochastic")

StochOverBought = input(80, title="Stochastic overbought condition")
StochOverSold = input(20, title="Stochastic oversold condition")

smoothK = input(3, title="smoothing of Stochastic %K ")

smoothD = input(3, title="moving average of Stochastic %K")

k = sma(stoch(close, high, low, Stochlength), smoothK)

d = sma(k, smoothD)

 
///////////// RSI 

RSIlength = input( 12, minval=1 , title="lookback length of RSI")

RSIOverBought = input( 65  , title="RSI overbought condition")

RSIOverSold = input( 35  , title="RSI oversold condition")

RSIprice = close
vrsi = rsi(RSIprice, RSIlength)

///////////// Double strategy: RSI strategy + Stochastic strategy

pd = input(22, title="LookBack Period Standard Deviation High")

bbl = input(20, title="Bolinger Band Length")

mult = input(2.0    , minval=1, maxval=5, title="Bollinger Band Standard Devaition Up")

lb = input(50  , title="Look Back Period Percentile High")

ph = input(.85, title="Highest Percentile - 0.90=90%, 0.95=95%, 0.99=99%")

new = input(false, title="-------Text Plots Below Use Original Criteria-------" )

sbc = input(false, title="Show Text Plot if WVF WAS True and IS Now False")

sbcc = input(false, title="Show Text Plot if WVF IS True")

new2 = input(false, title="-------Text Plots Below Use FILTERED Criteria-------" )

sbcFilt = input(true, title="Show Text Plot For Filtered Entry")

sbcAggr = input(true, title="Show Text Plot For AGGRESSIVE Filtered Entry")

ltLB = input(40, minval=25, maxval=99, title="Long-Term Look Back Current Bar Has To Close Below This Value OR Medium Term--Default=40")

mtLB = input(14, minval=10, maxval=20, title="Medium-Term Look Back Current Bar Has To Close Below This Value OR Long Term--Default=14")

str = input(3, minval=1, maxval=9, title="Entry Price Action Strength--Close > X Bars Back---Default=3")

//Alerts Instructions and Options Below...Inputs Tab

new4 = input(false, title="-------------------------Turn On/Off ALERTS Below---------------------" )

new5 = input(false, title="----To Activate Alerts You HAVE To Check The Boxes Below For Any Alert Criteria You Want----")

sa1 = input(false, title="Show Alert WVF = True?")

sa2 = input(false, title="Show Alert WVF Was True Now False?")

sa3 = input(false, title="Show Alert WVF Filtered?")

sa4 = input(false, title="Show Alert WVF AGGRESSIVE Filter?")

//Williams Vix Fix Formula

wvf = ((highest(close, pd)-low)/(highest(close, pd)))*100

sDev = mult * stdev(wvf, bbl)

midLine = sma(wvf, bbl)

lowerBand = midLine - sDev

upperBand = midLine + sDev

rangeHigh = (highest(wvf, lb)) * ph

//Filtered Bar Criteria

upRange = low > low[1] and close > high[1]

upRange_Aggr = close > close[1] and close > open[1]

//Filtered Criteria

filtered = ((wvf[1] >= upperBand[1] or wvf[1] >= rangeHigh[1]) and (wvf < upperBand and wvf < rangeHigh))

filtered_Aggr = (wvf[1] >= upperBand[1] or wvf[1] >= rangeHigh[1]) and not (wvf < upperBand and wvf < rangeHigh)

//Alerts Criteria

alert1 = wvf >= upperBand or wvf >= rangeHigh ? 1 : 0

alert2 = (wvf[1] >= upperBand[1] or wvf[1] >= rangeHigh[1]) and (wvf < upperBand and wvf < rangeHigh) ? 1 : 0

alert3 = upRange and close > close[str] and (close < close[ltLB] or close < close[mtLB]) and filtered ? 1 : 0

alert4 = upRange_Aggr and close > close[str] and (close < close[ltLB] or close < close[mtLB]) and filtered_Aggr ? 1 : 0

//Coloring Criteria of Williams Vix Fix

col = wvf >= upperBand or wvf >= rangeHigh ? color.lime : color.gray

isOverBought = (crossover(k,d) and k > StochOverBought) ? 1 : 0

isOverBoughtv2 = k > StochOverBought ? 1 : 0
filteredAlert = alert3 ? 1 : 0

aggressiveAlert = alert4 ? 1 : 0

plot(isOverBought, "Overbought / Crossover", style=plot.style_line, color=color.red) 

plot(filteredAlert, "Filtered Alert", style=plot.style_line, color=color.fuchsia) 

plot(aggressiveAlert, "Aggressive Alert", style=plot.style_line, color=color.orange)

Buy = (filteredAlert or aggressiveAlert)

Sell = (isOverBought)

alertcondition(Buy,  title='Ez Vix FIX / StochRSI, Long Alert',  message='BUY EzCONTINUOUS {{ticker}} {{high}} {{low}} {{close}}')

alertcondition(Sell, title='Ez Vix FIX / StochRSI, Short Alert', message='SELL EzCONTINUOUS {{ticker}} {{high}} {{low}} {{close}}')
```